# SSRS Query- Top X

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create a report which will show a table of locations and incident values in our case but only the top 20. I've put an example of it in Excel.

I don't see how it would be difficult to do this but I cannot seem to get this working.

Example table

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What is your problem. You need to give people more information if you expect help.

Comment: How is the data getting into the report?  Are you doing any additional filtering or grouping on the table in SSRS?  You need to provide a lot more contextual information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Hello, I have tried putting several queries in the report all which are brining back not all the results we need and just to top 20. Also we have filtered on the table top N 20 and this does not work. I'm not sure what you mean about getting the data. I'm doing a grouping on the table yes.